# create unique links to send to users

Tags: google-forms

I have been tasked with sending out a google forms link to a set of email addresses. I need each link to be unique so that a user can only answer the form once.

Is this possible with google forms?

The emails I send to will not necessarily have google accounts so the "limit to one response" will not be suitable as users will not be able to login to a google account to answer the form.

Many thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to create unique links to prevent that a user without a Google account submit more than one answer.

Regarding official documentation to support this, there isn't as usually Google only include the supported features. The close that you could find are feature requests on the [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/), posts on the [Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs).